# Are FIFA 2015 minimum required specs are supported by a Mac Retina with NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M video card?

Tags: graphics-card

I've read the specs for FIFA 15 at [EA official page](http://www.easports.com/fifa/news-updates-gameplay/article/fifa-15-features-info-pc) and found that the recommended video card is an NVIDIA GTX 460. I'm running FIFA 14 for Windows on a MacBook Retina 15"  Mid 2012 (using bootcamp) that has an NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M card. How could I be sure about the fitness of that Mac's card to run FIFA 15?

Comment: It appears that FIFA is for Windows only, is there something I've missed here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking if a certain computer can run a game.  We do not handle "Can I run it?" questions, as they are too localized to be useful to other users.

Comment: @Frank Can I use a question like 'is this card more powerful than that card' instead?

Comment: Nope; that's a graphics card comparison, which is still off-topic.  We decided a little over a year ago that graphics cards are not gaming specific hardware, therefore they don't belong here.  Besides, there are a ton of sites that do that already, and they do it much better than the Q&A format ever could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you read those specs properly. The NVIDIA GTX 460 was in the "Recommended" specifications, while the minimum lists the NVIDIA GTX 650.

A good way to measure performance is with benchmark scores. Here I will list the Passmark scores for the Recommended card, the Minimum card, and your card:

- [GeForce GTX 460](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/video_lookup.php?gpu=GeForce+GTX+460): 2,664
- [GeForce GTX 650](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/video_lookup.php?gpu=GeForce+GTX+650): 1,841
- [GeForce GT 650M](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/video_lookup.php?gpu=GeForce+GT+650M): 1,296

The requirements for Fifa 15 are unexpectedly higher than for Fifa 14. Until the game is released, it's not going to be possible to know just how well your card can play the game. However we can safely say that your card does **not** match the minimum requirements, so expect lower performance.